# automation to run script files for number of definition files using python

Tags: python, automation

I have an autojson file, where I need to run the file using the following command in the terminal:

```
python script.py -i input.json -o output.h
```

Now I want to run the same script for number of input files stored in a folder automatically and store the output in another folder. how can I write a python script to automate this?

For this to run I have to keep rewriting the input file names, instead the command should read the files from a given folder by itself and generate the files.

Comment: import os

os.system("DBM_cx.py -i DBM_AmData.json -o test.h")

Comment: i tried using the above command but it is not taking a path to execute. so cant add folder

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import subprocess

myFiles = []
cwd = os.getcwd()
path_script = cwd+"\\script"
myFiles = os.listdir(path_script)

for script_file in myFiles:
   x = os.path.join(path_def, filename)
   y = filename.strip(".json")
   os.system(script_file+" -i "+x+" -o "+y+".h")
```